# Continuous evaluation of AI Platform gives a `data_json_key` error

Tags: google-cloud-ml

With continuous evaluation of AI Platform, `data_json_key` error occurs.

**Evaluation Job Inputs**

- Model objective: Image object detection (box)
- IoU (Intersection over Union): 0.1
- Data key: b64
- Prediction label key: detection_classes
- Prediction score key: detection_scores
- Bounding box key: detection_boxes
- Labeling Service: No
- Daily sample percentage: 100%
- Daily sample limit: 100

**Error log**

```
Partial Failures: [{"code":5,"message":"Can not find the image data under the data_json_key: image_bytes/b64"},{"code":5,"message":"Can not find the image data under the data_json_key: image_bytes/b64"},{"code":5,"message":"Can not find the image data under the data_json_key: image_bytes/b64"},{"message":"Found incorrect number of labeled dataset when preparing evaluation for dataset_id: 5ee3023a_0000_25e5_a9d2_94eb2c19321a"}]
```

I have `data_json_key` set to `b64` and I think this is the correct predictive key for the model. However, the job returns an error as if it were expecting `image_bytes/b64`.

**Supplement**

The model is made by transfer learning `ssd_mobilenetv2_oidv4`*1 with TensorFlow Object Detection API according to this method*2.

1.https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md

2.https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/performing-prediction-with-tensorflow-object-detection-models-on-google-cloud-machine-learning-engine

Answer (score 0):

Your close. The Google documentation for Continuous Evaluation shows that data key is the key in the JSON example being submitted for prediction. In the AIP image classification example, the JSON is shown as:

```
{
  "instances": [
    {
      "image_bytes": {
        "b64": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAYAAAAGCAYAAADgzO9IAAAAhUlEQVR4AWOAgZeONnHvHcXiGJDBqyDTXa+dVC888oy51F9+eRdY8NdWwYz/RyT//znEsAjEt277+syt5VMJw989DM/+H2MI/L8tVBQk4d38xcWp7ctLhi97ZCZ0rXV6yLA4b6dH59sjTq3fnji1fp4AsWS5j7PXstRg+/b3gU7N351AQgA8+jkf43sjaQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**The tutorial the continues:**

Then provide the following keys:

Data key: image_bytes/b64
Prediction label key: sentiments
Prediction score key: confidence

Comment: Thanks for the reply. And sorry for the delay in my reply.I set the data key to `image_bytes/b64` and tried the continuous evaluation job again I tried to do this. The following error occurs.

Comment: ```
Partial Failures: [{"code":5, "message": "Can not find the image data under the data_json_key: image_bytes/b64"},{"code":5, "message": "Can not find the image data under the data_json_key: image_bytes/b64"},{"code":5, "message": "Can not find the image data under the data_json_key: image_bytes/b64"},{"message": "Found incorrect number of labeled dataset when preparing evaluation for dataset_id: xxx"}]
```

Comment: The response to the model's predictions is also an error.

Comment: ```
Using endpoint [https://ml.googleapis.com/]
{
  "error": "Prediction failed: Expected tensor name: inputs, got tensor name: ['image_bytes', ' key']." }
}```